# How to check if entry field value is already outputted, and prevent it again?

Tags: entry, field, filter

For an event page I have the option to filter on cities and countries. Each event has entry fields in which the city and country, of which the values are outputted in a drop down list on the front end.

As some events happen in the same country and city I have multipe values that are the same. Is there any chance to filter these values in Craft and output it only ones?

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('events') %}                      
    <option value="{{entry.stad}}" name="{{ entry.stad }}">{{ entry.stad }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft has a [`group filter`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#group), that does just that:

```
{% for stad, events in craft.entries.section('events') | group('stad') %}
    <option value="{{ stad }}">{{ stad }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are outputting the options, build an array of `stad` values and check for duplicates on each loop iteration. If the value does not exist in the array, add it to the array and print out the option.

```
{% set stad_array = [] %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('events') %}
    {% if entry.stad not in stad_array %}
        {% set stad_array = stad_array|merge([entry.stad]) %}
        <option value="{{entry.stad}}" name="{{ entry.stad }}">{{ entry.stad }}</option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) However, the other option is easier

Comment: Agreed! Glad you found a solution :)